# How to start action again after removeFromParent in Spritekit?

Tags: swift, skspritenode

Im running this action and I want it to stop when pressing a button. That works but when I try to run the action again it doesn't work anymore. Why does that happen?

```
    func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)



    let rotateRight = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 30, duration: 5.0)
    let rotateLeft = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -30, duration: 5.0)
    let sequenceRotation = SKAction.sequence([rotateRight, rotateLeft])
    let repeatSequence = SKAction.repeatForever(sequenceRotation)


    activityIndicator.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2.0, y: self.size.height / 2.0)
    activityIndicator.zPosition = 120
    activityIndicator.run(repeatSequence)
    addChild(activityIndicator)

}

 //calling this in a button when I want to stop rotating. 
 func stopRotating() {

 activityIndicator.removeFromParent() 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....

```
//call when to pause action
activityIndicator.isPaused = true

//call when to unpause action
activityIndicator.isPaused = false
```